# How to identify Data skew in spark jobs via web /yarn UI?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a spark job (HDInsight) and its run time is increasing slowly over the last couple of months. Based on the spark UI , are there any indicators to say that there is dataskew thats why its performance is degrading ? below is stage details, please see the median and 75th percentile difference. How should i go about optimizing this job ? appreciate any guidance

Also what is the optimal value for spark.sql.shuffle.partitions given the input dataset size is around 12 GB and cluster has got 128 cores ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Normally we use the following approach to identify possible stragglers and you have caught on to that:

> When Max duration among completed tasks is significanly higher than
> Median or 75th Percentile value, then this indicates the possibility
> of Stragglers.

The median in your case tells enough.

You need to salt the key to distribute the data better - which can be complicated, or look at current partitioning approach.

This article https://medium.com/swlh/troubleshooting-stragglers-in-your-spark-application-47f2568663ec provides good guidance.

Comment: Assuming we are hitting the dataskew issue, what are the options available to fix it  ? also does increasing # of shuffle.parititons in the configuration will help to mitigate this isssue ? Appreciate help from performance tuning experts

Comment: Also does repartitioning the dataframe which i believe has data skew will anyway help ? or its not

Comment: need to expiring with partitions strategies and shuffle partitions param. 200 is default

Comment: need to explore